# check if interface has property?

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, typescript-typings

Need to check if interface has specific property. Tried/googled, but could not find appropriate solution.
For example;

```
interface Props {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

What is best way to check if Props has "age" property?

Comment: Check when? At runtime? In a conditional type?

Comment: I need to use in conditional type.

Answer (score 2):

If what you're looking for is checking if a key exists at compile time in a type, you can use something like this:

```js
type ContainsKey<T, K extends string | number> = T extends { [key in K]: any }
  ? true
  : false

type contains1 = ContainsKey<Props, 'age'> // type contains1 = true
type contains2 = ContainsKey<Props, 'foo'> // type contains2 = false
```

Comment: Thanks, But it's not useful for my requirements.
I need for conditional check.
Like 
if( interface contain property) do certain thing

Comment: @ZAM - [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63248822/check-if-interface-has-property?noredirect=1#comment111877836_63248822) you said you need to use it in a conditional type. A [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) is not an if statement (it's a type like the one in gZjose's answer).

Answer (score 1):

In [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63248822/check-if-interface-has-property?noredirect=1#comment111877887_63249555) you've said:

> I need for conditional check. Like if( interface contain property) do certain thing

You can't do that. Interfaces don't exist at runtime when `if` statements are executed. All of TypeScript's type information is erased when compiling from TypeScript to JavaScript (there are some objects created by `enum`, but the type information related to them is gone).

You can check if an *object* has a particular property at runtime:

```
// Check if it has a property (either as an own property or an inherited one)
if ("propertyName" in someObject) {
    // ...yes, it does...
}
```

or

```
// Check if it has a property (as an own property, ignoring inherited ones)
if (someObject.hasOwnProperty("propertyName")) {
    // ...yes, it does...
}
```

Some folks consider you shouldn't use `hasOwnProperty` as a method like that because it can be overridden and that you should use the one on `Object.prototype` instead:

```
// Check if it has a property (as an own property, ignoring inherited ones)
if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(someObject, "propertyName")) {
    // ...yes, it does...
}
```